# Where is Launcher.qml in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: unity, 14.04, launcher

Where is`/usr/share/unity-2d/shell/launcher/Launcher.qml` (From 12.04) located in Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It went into oblivion. 14.04 does not have a unity-2d session so also no Launcher.qml to start unity-2d. It was removed when 12.10 got released and so was all the code in the repositories.

If you need lighter version than Unity consider lUbuntu or xUbuntu or the GNOME Flashback.

From [omgubuntu.co.uk](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/04/ubuntu-14-04-classic-gnome-flashback-session):

> **Install GNOME Flashback in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS**
>
> To get the best of the modern desktop but with the simplicity offered by that old school two panel vibe the GNOME Flashback session available in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is well worth giving a go.
>   session-chooser-ubuntu-lightdm
>
> Select the session at the Unity Greeter
>
> Flashback is available to install from the Ubuntu Software Centre (unlike Cinnamon) and is styled like the Ubuntu desktop of old. It offers everything you need to get work done without putting strain on system resources or your muscle memory!
>
> It might not be as forward-looking or ‘academically efficient’ as Unity, but if you’re more interested in getting things done than having things get in the way, it’s by far an easier option than opting for an entirely different OS.

Comment: Does this mean that there is now no way to edit the unity launcher?

Comment: Besides unity8.desktop (/usr/share/app-install/desktop/)I see no desktop files related to unity itself. And there is no Launcher.qml on my system. So the answer is probably no :)